# Setting up Cron Job and Sending News Letter in Magento

Tags: php, magento, cron

I'm a front end developer working on Magento cms. I have created a newsletter template and I want to test if it is sending, I queued the newsletter and submit waiting to receive. However, I'm not receiving any. I tried to send it everyday but until now, no single news letter was received.

I tried to read about it and I came about this magento admin Cron (Scheduled Tasks).

> I set it to 60, 1, 60, 120, 120, 120 in chronological order.

I also tried to set a cron job schedule on the server. Since mydomain.com is an addon test domain and the magento directory is under public_html/test/, I set the server cron jobs to this

```
0   0   *   *   *   curl -L -s http://www.example.com/cron.php
```

I'm still not receiving any newsletter with this set up.

What set up should I do to make it run? I'm I in a right path?

Answer (score 0):

**For Cron Job Check in Magento:**

To ensure that Cron Job is working or not, you can install AOE Scheduler Extension.
https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/aoe-scheduler.html

**To Set Cron on Server:**

You can set cron job on server for every 5 minutes:

`php -f /home/fullpath/public_html/cron.php`

**Debug:**

If cron Job still not work, Please add following code:

`$isShellDisabled = true;`

After below line of code:

`$isShellDisabled = (stripos(PHP_OS, 'win') === false) ? $isShellDisabled : true;`